# See progress bar on upload video on server using redux and react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, form-data, react-dropzone

I want to upload video on server Video upload successfully but i want progress bar for video but how did i do that i didn't figure out i am using react-dropzone and redux please help.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { CDragAndDrop } from '../../uiComponents'
import { updateIntroductoryVideo } from '../../store/actions/Users';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

 function IntroductoryVideo() {
   const [file, updateFile] = useState(null);
   const dispatch = useDispatch();


   const uploadVideoCallback = () => {
      updateFile(null)
   } 

   const uploadVideo = () => {
      console.log(file, "file")
      let body = new FormData();
      body.append("personalVideo", file);
      dispatch(updateIntroductoryVideo(body, uploadVideoCallback));
   };

   const uploadFile = (file) => {
      updateFile(file);
   };


  return (
      <div className="d-flex flex-column">
          <CDragAndDrop callBack={uploadFile} IntroductoryVideo={"introductoryVideo"} 
             className="large" />
          <button className="c-button mt-5" onClick={uploadVideo} >Upload</button>
      </div>
   )
  }


 export default IntroductoryVideo
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a progressbar you have 2 options:

- Progressbar withouth progress: You can just set a flag before you start to upload the file and remove it when it complete. With this way you can just read that flag and show any kind of "spinner" or "progress bar without real progress" to provide feedback to user.
- Progressbar with progress: To use this way you have to know the actual progress of your upload. I'm not sure how you are making this or how can you get this, but in case you can get the actual progress you only have to set a progressbar with this actual progress as the percentage of upload completion.

I think your main problem is more about the way to get this progress, when you get it you only has to show it in a graphic way, maybe storing it in state, or directly from where you get it.

Comment: I want second option but I dont know how to get progress from server

Comment: You can use something like this if you are using XMLHttpRequest: https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/issues/125#issuecomment-274943457, if you are using Axios you can use onUploadProgress, with other libraries I have to check it

Comment: can you please tell me onuploadprogress how to use it i use it but no response

Comment: It's documented here https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config, you can take a look